# SQL Server | Is my stored procedure is OK?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCountTableRowWHere
    @TblName VARCHAR(50),
    @TblID VARCHAR(10) = 'Id',
    @WhereClause NVARCHAR(500) = '1=1'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @Count INT
    SET @Query = 'SELECT @C = COUNT('+@TblID+') FROM '+@TblName+' WHERE '+@WhereClause
    SET @ParamDefinition = '@C INT OUTPUT'

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Query, @ParamDefinition, @C = @Count OUTPUT
    SELECT @Count
END
```

I am wondering if this kind of procedure is better than a separate procedures for different tables.

Comment: erm, why do you even need such a proc?

Comment: Don't use sp -prefix in your procedures, it's meant for system procedures and has a special meaning

Comment: @MitchWheat, i will use it in my vb app

Comment: ", i will use it in my vb app " - is not a reason.

Comment: @JamesZ: actually, it's the `sp_` (**with** the underscore) that is the reserved prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.
The long answer is that it is an opening to sql injection attacks.
Think what will happen if someone will put the following string in your where clause argument: `1=1; drop table myTable`.

Comment: Thanks @Zohar Peled , i forgot the sql injection -_- sorry guys for the noob question